# clFinish takes forever, independent of kernel complexity and global_size

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I am currently working on an OpenCL project, where I encountered a strange behaviour.

AMD APP SDK: OpenCL v1.2
HD 7770

**The kernel is the following one, probably the most simple one you can imagine:**

```
__kernel void bm_and(
__global const unsigned int* const bitmap1,
__global const unsigned int* const bitmap2,     
__global unsigned int* const result ) 
{   
    size_t gi = get_global_id(0);   
    if (gi >= get_global_size(0))       
        return;     
    result[gi] = bitmap1[gi] & bitmap2[gi];  
}
```

The problem I have is, that doesn't matter how big the global size I call the kernel with is, it seems like I have a constant delay of about 1.5 seconds in the call to clFinish afterwards.

This happens only on the 1st call to bm_and, further calls operate at a regular performance.

**Abstract Example**

```
//time ~1.5s (doesn't matter if bitmaps are 1 or 100M)
clFinish(queue)
start = now
bm_and(x,y,z)
clFinish(queue)
end = now
time = end-start

//time ~1.5s, second kernel call and clFinish execute at a high performance+
clFinish(queue)
start = now
bm_and(x,y,z)
clFinish(queue)
bm_and(x,y,z)
clFinish(queue)
end = now
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help, transfer cost probably isn't the problem since the delay seems to be independent from the size of the bitmaps I use and the data is already on the device.

**EDIT:**
The kernel performance itself doesn't seem to be the problem,
the time seems to get lost between submitting and starting the kernel.

Those are example outputs of

> clGetEventProfilingInfo

```
QUEUE  MS: 5497240.33
SUMBIT MS: 5497240.36
START  MS: 5498938.58
END    MS: 5498938.94
```

Comment: How big are your bitmaps?  How are they copied to the device?

Comment: I tested it with sizes starting at a couple of kB to ~200M. The delay stayed the same. The bitmaps aren't copied to the device, they are populated on the device by preceding kernels so they are already on the device when submitting the and kernel

Comment: You should try adding a clFinish before the first bm_and, to make sure the execution of all preceding kernels are complete, and have correct time measurement.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just forget to mention that in the post - I already did that

Comment: I have a similar issue with the Intel runtime, but in my case the clFinish call does take forever, as in, an infinite amount of time. It just never returns! Very frustrating.